# Keeping <details> tag opened after applying closeAll after I click on content in the tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used the `<details>` and `<summary>` tags to create collapsible menus with buttons to open certain elements on the page, but when I click a button it closes the collapsed menu. How can I keep that collapsed menu opened after clicking a button within that menu?

I have used the `onclick="closeAll()"` to close all the menus while I open one, but just need to keep the menu open that I am on after I click a button within that menu (to show users where they have navigated from).

Here is part of my code:

```
<details onclick="closeAll()">
  <summary>
    <div class="menubut" id="butmotors"><img src="gfx/menu_motors.png" /></div>
  </summary>
  <input type="button" value="Your Garage" class="sub_but" onclick="your_garage();"><br />
  <input type="button" value="Travel By Car" class="sub_but" onclick="travel();"><br />
  <input type="button" value="Car Dealership" class="sub_but" onclick="car_dealership();"><br />
  <input type="button" value="Street Race" class="sub_but" onclick="street_racer();"><br />
  <input type="button" value="Gas Station" class="sub_but" onclick="show_gas_station();">
</details>';

function closeAll() {
  var i, a = document.getElementsByTagName('details');
  for (i in a) {
    a[i].open = '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I would do is to stop using the inline event attributes.

Then, to be able to have an event handler binded to a child element (your buttons) of another element which also has an event handler, the trick you need to know is the jQuery [`.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

That is preventing the event from bubbling up to the parent...

And below (as a bonus), I used only one function binded to the `sub_but` class for all the buttons. Then, using [`switch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), decide what to do based on the value of the clicked button.

The [`details`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) tag is interesting. I wasn't aware about it. It has a boolean attribute to expand/collapse it... But surprisingly, the values are `false` for collapsed or `""` for opened (`true` doesn't seem to work... And that is good to know).

```js
// The arrow click handler
$("details").on("click",function(){
  console.log("You clicked on the detail arrow");
  
  // Close all other details tags.
  $("details").each(function(){
    this.open = false;
  });
});

// The button click handler
$(".sub_but").on("click",function(event){

  // To top the event from bubbling up
  event.stopPropagation();
  
  // Evaluate which button was clicked
  switch(this.value){
    case "Your Garage":
      console.log("You clicked Your Garage");
      // Do something specific here...
      break;
    
    case "Travel By Car":
      console.log("You clicked Travel By Car");
      // Do something specific here...
      break;
    
    case "Car Dealership":
      console.log("You clicked Car Dealership");
      // Do something specific here...
      break;
    
    case "Street Race":
      console.log("You clicked Street Race");
      // Do something specific here...
      break;
    
    case "Gas Station":
      console.log("You clicked Gas Station");
      // Do something specific here...
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<details>
  <summary>
    <div class="menubut" id="butmotors"><img src="gfx/menu_motors.png" /></div>
  </summary>
  <input type="button" value="Your Garage" class="sub_but"><br />
  <input type="button" value="Travel By Car" class="sub_but"><br />
  <input type="button" value="Car Dealership" class="sub_but"><br />
  <input type="button" value="Street Race" class="sub_but"><br />
  <input type="button" value="Gas Station" class="sub_but">
</details>

<details>
  <summary>
    Some other details...
  </summary>
  What could be interesting to know?
</details>
```

*Better try the snippet in full page because of the console logs...*

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question i really appreciate your help, i've been stuck on this for 3 days :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the final code i needed and Louys Patrice Bessette's answer is absolutely correct thank you!

```
    // The arrow click handler
$("details").on("click",function(){
  //console.log("You clicked on the detail arrow");

  // Close all other details tags.
  $("details").each(function(){
    this.open = false;
  });
});

// The button click handler
$(".sub_but").on("click",function(event){

  // To top the event from bubbling up
  event.stopPropagation();

});
```